# return a output linux log file in formatted way

Tags: python, django

Hi I am using django and following the below method in views.py to return a output file,

```
response = HttpResponse(content=log_file)
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/txt:html'
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Now the issue is when I return the file in browser is displayed without /n (next line)

my actual file content is,

```
../xyz/value.txt
../abc/cls.txt
../opt/value.txt
../zz.txt
```

But it is display as,

../xyz/value.txt ../abc/cls.txt ../opt/value.txt ../zz.txt

when I open the same file with vim editor in linux machine it displays properly but here when I return from views and read it in browser it shows without /n

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try `text = text.replace("\n","</BR>")` to force html newlines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n

Comment: I mean `<BR/>` sorry

Comment: What kind of mime type is `application/txt:html`? Try `text/plain` instead, maybe? If the content is displayed as html, all whitespace is truncated, so tabs, newlines and spaces all display as a single space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I serve a text file from Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503062/how-do-i-serve-a-text-file-from-django)

Answer (score 0):

StreamingHttpResponse response from djanto.http solved the issue as below,

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def display_text(request):
    content = open(log_file).read()
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(content)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset=utf8'
    return response
```