# Django create dynamic txt file and download with special file name

Tags: django

I am trying create dynamic text file and download it when my method called.I used steps at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14503062/7659834").But when I change the file name, file isn't downloaded, displayed on browser. What can I do ? My code is below. Thanks for advice.

```
def view_method(request):
    file_name = 'students.txt'
    lines = []
    data = Student.objects.all()
    for d in data:
       lines.append('{0};{1};{2}'.format(d.name,d.surname,d.amount))
    response_content = '\n'.join(lines)
    response = HttpResponse(response_content, content_type="text/plain,charset=utf8")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(file_name)
    return response
```

Comment: The code you provided won't run. Confirm your code is correct.

Comment: I edited my code.Thanks your warning.

Comment: Still won't. Copy/Paste it and fix your errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with correct the file name chars.My file name contains utf-8 characters and points.